# Vim immediately sent to background

Tags: vimrc, startup, job-control

Whenever I call Vim from the CLI, either to edit a file (`vim idk.tex`) or without arguments, or run a command (`vim +help`), it gets sent to the background, as if I had pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

In order to use it, I always have to send the job to foreground, either to wait for it to finish or to begin working in Vim.

I've tried this on Zsh, bash, fish and tmux (with each shell), and it's always the same behavior.

I can't reproduce it with [minivimrc](https://github.com/bling/minivimrc), so I don't know if I should report it as an Airline bug or not.

I have hacked up an alias (`vim="vim;fg"`) so that it won't bug me daily, but it's not feasible when I have other background jobs or when vim fails to start for whatever reason (besides, it's just a hack).

Any pointers as to where I should look or ask are welcome.

I'm running Vim (GVim package) on Termite (v12) on Arch (fully up to date)

My vimrc is:

```
" for when using elsewhere
set fsync backspace=indent,eol,start updatetime=1500
set shell=bash\ -i
" search candy
set incsearch nohlsearch ignorecase smartcase

" useful shiz
set number hidden cursorline cursorcolumn
set splitright
set mouse=a mousefocus clipboard=unnamedplus
set smarttab autoindent copyindent
set scrolloff=2   " 2 lines of context when scrolling
syntax enable
set history=1000 undolevels=1000
" non-printable and double-width chars
set list listchars=tab:>-,trail:Â·,extends:#,nbsp:Â·
set ambiwidth=single
" tab -> 2 spaces, autoindent when pasting
set expandtab tabstop=2
" default tab->2 spaces, use multiples of 2 when autoindenting
set softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 shiftround
" wrap shiz
set wrap linebreak nolist
set directory=/tmp   " store swap files here
filetype on
filetype indent plugin on
set ttimeoutlen=10
set noshowmode
set showcmd
set colorcolumn=80
hi ColorColumn ctermbg=7
```

Answer (score 2):

I shouldn't have set the shell as interactive. Somehow it pauses the main Vim process.

So:

```
set shell=bash\ -i
```

Should be:

```
set shell=bash
```